# share database with others in Sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, git

I am using Sql server management studio 2012 . I want to share my database tables with my friend having different server. Like I am using git and me and my friend working on same project when i code i commit and push and he pulls the code . We want the same thing for database , like i add or update table and then commit and push but the problem is that i have different server and my friend has different. So there will be problem in connection string . Is any software or tool exists that resolve my problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a tool for this you can use the redgate source control [tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/).
Another option would be if you could make your SQL server publicly accessible. By doing that your friend and you could work on the same database.